# How to set a type DNS?

Tags: nameserver, dns-hosting

I have a dedicated hosting and I am trying to set the dns on the server side to an a type dns. Lets say my domain is: myDomain.com and I  have already pointed it at the registery to ns1.myDomain.com and ns2.myDomain.com. This is supposed to point at an IP. I manage the server with DirectAdmin and the server runs on Centos.

The problem: I don't seem to be able to set the domain at my server correctly. I have gone so many ways that I don't know if I already set something wrong somewhere else but whenever I try to go to the domain at the browser I get: **myDomains.com’s server DNS address could not be found.**

To make the question summirize: How do I set an a type dns through DirectAdmin or SSH having the IP?

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you are asking. Are you running a DNS nameserver on your host and need help adding an A record?  Or is the nameserver somewhere else and you need help adding an A record there?  Have you asked your hosting and/or DNS provider for help?

Comment: If you provided the true domain name you are using people would be able to better understand your problem and give you better help. So, provide the domain name involved without useless obfuscation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you've set the correct nameservers for your domain and they should be resolved to your dedicated server /DNS server. Also check if you've created a correct DNSzone file (with the DNS records) for your domain in your DNS server, hosted on your dedicated server.